# Strain relief removal on LG Dryer

Tags: wiring, dryer

I have a LG dryer that I need to change the power cable from 4 wire to 3.  The existing cable has an rubber strain relief around the cable. It does the job well as I cannot remove the cable. I would like to keep my 4 wire cable. Any ideas on how to remove the cable and the strain relief.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If dryer came with 4 wire cable, do not think you are allowed to change to 3 wire.  Good chance that dryer will not work and be dangerous with just a 3 wire cable.  If power outlet is 3 prong, then need to upgrade to 4 prong outlet and cable.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the outlet box in/on the wall please?  I want to rule out the possibility that you should be changing the receptacle instead of the cord...

Comment: it may not be possible to salvage  both the strain relieif and the cable.

Comment: You would be better off converting the receptacle to 4-wire. Happens all the time where the wiring is 4-wire but they change the socket to 3-wire at the request of the homeowner.  Or it may be metal conduit and ground via the conduit shell.  Either of those will allow a 4-wire socket.  Alternately, a #10 ground wire can be retrofit.  Or, the 4-wire socket can be fit without a ground, by using a 2-pole GFCI receptacle.